# Where do I put SQL in my code when using notepad?

Tags: sql, notepad

Lets say I have some code where I will be using just javascript, html, and css. I would create an outline like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<script>

</script>
<body>
    <button>Create a new table</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But what I want is when the user clicks a button it can create a table using SQL. My question is do I put that code in the script tags() or create separate tags for the SQL part?

Comment: You'll need some kind of server-side code for that other than client-side javascript.

Comment: Brooke, Welcome to SO. As is your question is way to broad, and will likely be closed. Your SQL query work will be done on the backend, not the front end.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot execute SQL from an HTML file. That requires server side processing with PHP, Ruby, Python, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this information, but I am very new and have never done server side processing. Where can I learn more about how to do this?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials. I personally like Tutorial Republic. You can find their PHP tutorials here: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/

Comment: Also, please make the answer as "Solved." Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

umm, there's a certain amount of knowledge to the MySql part needed.

The MySql commands are normally handled by a language called php. Doing it with javascript is rather exotic I think.

There really are a million online tutorials on php/MySql

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: There are many more choices than PHP…

Comment: Sure but what's the obvious one for someone starting out, i think the 'normally' covered this point